# web2py: drop all tables in a database in one statement?

Tags: database, web2py

I was wondering if web2py offers any way to drop all tables at once, without having to specify each table to be deleted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your database backend?

Answer (score 5):

`db.tables()` returns a list with the names of all tables in the database `db`

So you can do:

```
for table_name in db.tables():
    db[table_name].drop()

db.commit()
```

*(The final `db.commit()` is only necessary if Web2Py isn't committing your DAL changes automatically, for example from the command line interface.)*

Comment: In my use case, I needed to re-populate my database (using db_wizard_populate.py) after changes in schema. For this, one does not have to `drop()`, but `truncate()`.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer has one problem -- if you are using more than one database, you could accidentally drop tables from the wrong DB if you make a cut-and-paste error.  Example --

```
for table_name in db_one.tables():
    db_two[table_name].drop()
```

If you copy code from one model or app to another, it is too easy to edit one db reference and not the other.  If db_two has tables with names matching some tables in db_one, you could drop a table in the wrong database.  Better to write a trivial function that takes db as a parameter --

```
def dropdb(thedb):
    for table_name in thedb.tables():
        thedb[table_name].drop()
```

"Don't repeat yourself".